# Is there a concise way to denote two sets that do not contain each other but have non-empty intersection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A$ and $B$ two sets. Is there any concise way to write these three conditions together?

$$A\not\subseteq B \quad\text{and}\quad B\not\subseteq A \quad\text{and}\quad A\cap B \neq \emptyset$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of to write it is $B\setminus A\neq \emptyset \neq A\setminus B \neq A$, though I'm not sure this is better than what you proposed.

Another way would be to use symmetric difference (defined by $X\mathrel{\bigtriangleup}Y=(X\cup Y)\setminus (X\cap Y)$) and say $A\mathrel{\bigtriangleup}B\neq A\cup B\not\in\{A,B\}$.